# What is the function to define the minimum and maximum length of a integer variable in joi module

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

What is the function to define the minimum and maximum length of a integer variable in joi module

```
const schema =joi.object().keys( {

num : joi.number().minlength(12).maxlength(12)  });
```

Comment: did you find an answer @aishwary-joshi? I happen to have same question

Answer (score 3):

why don't you use like this .min(111) instead of determining the length. This .min() will automatically does your required work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi

Comment: This package has been deprecated

Answer (score 3):

you are dealing with **numbers not string**

**min and max** only applicable for string types to limit character length

use **greater and less** for number types

**example**: must be 6-10, so only 6,7,8,9,10

```
Joi.number().greater(5).less(11)
```

Answer (score 1):

For validate max and min integer value use:
 `joi.number().integer().min(12).max(13).`

You can see Joi documentation [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md)

Comment: I don't wan't the min and  max allowed number, I need to know the min and max length just like we do in array, so what's the function to set the minimum and maximum length like only 12 digits are allowed

Answer (score 1):

You'd want something like `Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(9999999999)`. This is assuming you want `mo` to be an integer with a "length" of 10.

Answer (score 1):

you could do `Joi.number().integer().min(100000000000).max(999999999999)` assuming your number is a **true** number without leading zeros. Otherwise, you could do `Joi.string().length(12)` - joi will convert the number to a string in this case and do its validation.